# Godot Export Similar to Exported Dictionary

Tags: c#, game-development, godot

In Godot, when a Dictionary is exported, it appears in the inspector with the ability to select what variable types the keys and values will be.

[Exported Dictionary Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cRWP.png)
[Exported Dictionary Variable Key/Value Type Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LemLI.png)

I am creating a system that needs a lot of flexibility, and it seems like being able to export a variable in this format is exactly what I'm looking for.

Looking at the documentation, it appears that when a dictionary is exported without specifying types, such as:

```
[Export] private Godot.Collections.Dictionary dictionary;
```

(And to my understanding even if types are specified), the types for the keys and values are `Variant`. Unfortunately, when I try to export a variable of type Variant using:

```
[Export] private Variant variant;
```

It shows up in the inspector as a null field that cannot be edited:

[Exported Variant Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfAMp.png)

Is there a way to export a variable in the same format as the dictionary, but for a single variable? I could use a dictionary and just only use the keys or values but that seems hacky, so I was wondering if there was an export that has this functionality, as it seems like it is already possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Not out of the box, at the time of writing. Closest I can think of is an array of variant for which you define a setter that forces it to have only one element. Edit: it might be possible to add this feature with an inspector addon, although that approach would require to recreate the UI, and there is an issue with determining if a `null` is a variant.